# Passing parameters to customized transformer

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline

I customized a transformer like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, QuantileTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin 

class CorrWeight(TransformerMixin):
    """Calculate the weights of metrics based on their correlations, and transform to scores based on the resulting weights."""

    def fit(self, X, y, **fit_params):
        self.offset = offset
        self.max_weight = max_weight
        corr_mat = pd.DataFrame(X).corr()
        # Sum over all correlations to get an overall correlation score for each metric
        metric_summary = corr_mat.sum().to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'overall correlation'})
        # Assign a weight to each metric that is inversely related to the overall correlation
        # so that the higher the overall correlation, the lower the weight
        if self.max_weight > 1:
            metric_summary['weight'] = 1 / MinMaxScaler((1 / self.max_weight, 1)).fit_transform(
                metric_summary[['overall correlation']])
        elif self.max_weight == 1:
            metric_summary['weight'] = 1
        else:
            print("Max_weight has to be no smaller than 1!")
            metric_summary['weight'] = 1
        self.metric_summary = metric_summary
        return self

    def transform(self, X, **fit_params):
        # Multiply the rescaled metrics together (with the weight being the exponent for each metric)
        score = np.exp(pd.DataFrame(np.log(X + self.offset) * np.array(self.metric_summary['weight'])).sum(axis=1))
        return pd.DataFrame(score)

    def fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params):
        self.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
        return self.transform(X)
```

And used it in a pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('transformations', QuantileTransformer()),
    ('rescale_metrics', MinMaxScaler()),
    ('weighting', CorrWeight()),
    ('rescale_score', MinMaxScaler())
])
```

However when I try to pass parameters to the customized transformer:

```
params = {'weighting__offset': 2,
          'weighting__max_weight': 5}

pipeline.fit(metrics, [], **params)
```

I got the error message saying

```
NameError: name 'offset' is not defined
```

What is the right way to pass in the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the parameters of the transformer in the constructor function itself. Even if you want to tune those hyper parameters, then having it in constructor is the best way.

Try this!

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, QuantileTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin 

class CorrWeight(TransformerMixin):
    """Calculate the weights of metrics based on their correlations, and transform to scores based on the resulting weights."""
    def __init__(self,offset,max_weight):
        self.offset = offset
        self.max_weight = max_weight

    def fit(self, X, y):
         #remove the fit_params here
        corr_mat = pd.DataFrame(X).corr()
        # Sum over all correlations to get an overall correlation score for each metric
        metric_summary = corr_mat.sum().to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'overall correlation'})
        # Assign a weight to each metric that is inversely related to the overall correlation
        # so that the higher the overall correlation, the lower the weight
        if self.max_weight > 1:
            metric_summary['weight'] = 1 / MinMaxScaler((1 / self.max_weight, 1)).fit_transform(
                metric_summary[['overall correlation']])
        elif self.max_weight == 1:
            metric_summary['weight'] = 1
        else:
            print("Max_weight has to be no smaller than 1!")
            metric_summary['weight'] = 1
        self.metric_summary = metric_summary
        return self

    def transform(self, X, **fit_params):
        # Multiply the rescaled metrics together (with the weight being the exponent for each metric)
        score = np.exp(pd.DataFrame(np.log(X + self.offset) * np.array(self.metric_summary['weight'])).sum(axis=1))
        return pd.DataFrame(score)

    def fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params):
        self.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
        return self.transform(X)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('transformations', QuantileTransformer()),
    ('rescale_metrics', MinMaxScaler()),
    ('weighting', CorrWeight(offset=2,max_weight=5)), 
    #feed the params value when you define the transformer
    ('rescale_score', MinMaxScaler())
])

pipeline.fit(np.random.rand(10,10), []) # you can remove the params here
```

May be if you strictly want to have it as fit_params, then define the fit function, in the following way:

```
def fit(self, X, y, offset=None,max_weight=None):
    self.offset = offset
    self.max_weight = max_weight
    ...
```